# PHP Explode using inside of database

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my database the date is like this 24 june 2016, 09:17. And there are many data in my db. I am gonna use this code in my web site.

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siparisler where tarih='$nwdate' ");

echo $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

I am checking today's date. But only date not time. However my database has time and date. I want this; If the date of today same with my any dates in my db, show me how many data in my db. For example my new data is like this 3 june 2016 but in my db like this 3 june 2016, 09:17. How can it work.

I want something like this

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siparisler where explode(",", date[0])='$nwdate' ");

Comment: try using `CURDATE()` native mysql function to get today's data like this : `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM siparisler where date=CURDATE() ")`

Comment: What type of field is  `date` in the database?

Comment: `$t2 = date($t);` is absolute nonsense. What's that supposed to do?

Comment: What type is your `date` column in your database? `DATETIME`? `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the comma to the date format and then use only first part of exploded array, so part of code is:

```
$t    =   date("Y-m-d, H:i:s");

$nwdate   = explode(",", $t)[0];
```

Moreover you don't need this row, is useless. Delete it and use only variable $t.

```
$t2   =   date($t);
```

Comment: Or, you know… just do `date('Y-m-d')` to begin with...!?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Ok I will change my db. Normally date and time together. And I need those together. I am gonna change. It will not together. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $t    =   date("Y-m-d");